# Есть ли метод в google map для районов

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Вот [пример отрисовки региона на google map](https://www.google.ru/maps/place/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9+%D1%80-%D0%BD,+%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2,+%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB./@51.5804094,45.9547068,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x4114c898011f1809:0xacc6bbdcab5c6620!8m2!3d51.556077!4d46.0070257), есть ли в гугл апи метод чтобы районы сами так обрисовывались вместо того чтобы самому рисовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему все легко и просто https://youtu.be/9AIlbwxClo0